# In what sequence cluster analysis is done?

Tags: database, cluster-analysis, data-mining

First find the minimum frequent patterns from the database.
Then divide them into various data types like interval based , binary ,ordinal variables etc and define various distance measures for all the variables.
Finally apply cluster analysis method.

Is this sequence right or am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

whether you're right or not depends on what you want to do. The general approach that you describe seems to go into the right direction, but you'll never know if your on target until you answer the following questions:

1. What is your data?
2. What are trying to find/Which cluster method do you want to use?

From what you describe it seems to me that you want to do 'preprocessing' steps like feature selection and vectorization. Unfortunately, this by itself can be quite challenging. For example, one of the biggest partical problems is the design of a distance function (there's a tremendous amount of research available).

So, please give us more information on your specific target application.